# Elegant arguments in constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor

Is there a elegant way to pass multiple arguments to a constructor?

This is my constructor:

```
public _Empresa(string n, string r, string d, int l, string c, string f, string t, string m, string o)
{
    e_nombre = n;
    e_rfc = r;
    e_direccion = d;
    e_delegacion = l;
    e_cp = c;
    e_referencias = f;
    e_telefono = t;
    e_email = m;
    e_observaciones = o;
}
```

Lately in a windows form I call that constructor

```
public _Empresa empresa
{
    get
    {
        return new _Empresa(_nombre.Text, _rfc.Text, _direccion.Text, int.Parse(_delegacion.SelectedValue.ToString()), _cp.Text, _referencias.Text, _telefono.Text, _email.Text, _observaciones.Text);
    }
}
```

They aren't same type so no chance of sending an array. What other options do i have?

Comment: Use a [parameter object](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some of those properties are related, you could group them into smaller classes on their own (so you could pass in an instance of that class to the constructor of your class). However that would just spread your initialization to two or three smaller objects, so you should do it only if it makes logical sense for your code, not only to make your constructor more readable.

One thing that may make your code more readable is using named parameters and some indentation:

```
new _Empresa(
  n: _nombre.Text, 
  r: _rfc.Text
  ...
  );
```

which would also look better if the parameter names were more self-descriptive

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I was looking for. A more readable way of doing it whithout the need of creating a helper class. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

You can pass in a class that has properties you need in your constructor.

#### Sample

**the arguments class**

```
public class EmpresaConstructorArguments
{
     public string Nombre { get;set }
        // ...
}
```

**the constructor**

```
public _Empresa(EmpresaConstructorArguments arg)
{
        e_nombre = arg.Nombre;
        // ...
}
```

**or**

```
private EmpresaConstructorArguments Arguments;

public _Empresa(EmpresaConstructorArguments arg)
{
        this.Arguments = arg; 
}
```

Check out [MSDN - ProcessStartInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).

> Specifies a set of values that are used when you start a process.

### Update

Another approach is to pass in the values with named arguments.

Assuming your class looks like this

```
public _Empresa empresa
{
    public string Nombre { get; set }
    // ...
}

you can do 

new _Empresa { Nombre : _nombre.Text }
```

Comment: See [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) for an example from the BCL.

Comment: Good answer however It would be a pain to do this for the multiple classes I have in my app. Maybe I just need something more readable like the answer below.

Comment: @JorgeZapata my answer is extended.

Comment: Named arguments was my choice since I don't want to create a helper class for every constructor. Thanks for showing me a lot of options.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object that contains all of the arguments and pass that instead.
The fact there's so many of them tells you they probably have some kind of relation that may be worthy of a class anyway.